# Fonts affecting overall programs on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: fonts

I installed some fonts a while ago on my Ubuntu 20.04. I created three directories (otf, ttc, ttf) under another directory I also created named 'downloaded_fonts', which was created under `/usr/share/fonts`.
Those fonts were zipped in a file; I unziped them, and moved them all accordingly in those three directories: otf, ttc, ttf.
After that the `(` and `)` symbols were in italics in some applications (such as Firefox). When I tried to open GIMP the initial text was all tofu and then it crashed immediately.
Both problems were solved by simply moving the `downloaded_fonts` directory out of `/usr/share/fonts` (I moved it to the Downloads directory).

After that I installed Krita. The problem is: there are no min/max/close buttons on Krita (although the close button works if I click where it should be); also the document title's characters  at the top of the window (as well as the sub-menus') are all tofu.

How can I prevent these weird font interactions?

I'm new to Ubuntu and trying to figure this all out

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any font in `/usr/share/fonts/any-folder-name/` will be used / can be recognized by applications like firefox, libreoffice. .... Better delete the "downloaded_fonts" folder, etc. folders with incompatible / corrupt fonts in "/usr/share/fonts/".

Comment: Title bar icons issue is not a font interaction, but different. I suggest you try staying away from directly manipulating your system folders. Custom fonts can also be placed - more safely - under a .local/config/fonts directory in your home directory.

Comment: Your edit should probably be posted as an answer, as that seems to be a possible solution/workaround.

Answer (score 0):

> The buttons' problem was solved by itself [?], I'm not really sure
> how. I ran the following commands, which solved the title bar
> problems: `rm -rf ~/.cache/fontconfig/` `sudo fc-cache -r` It
> cleared the fonts' cache and everything was smooth again. I also
> followed one of the replies (but a bit differently) and moved the
> fonts directory under `/home/[user]/.local/share/fonts`. I just
> noticed that the 'italics' problem returned, so one of the fonts is
> (or some of them are) corrupted.

This is copy to separate answer from new user question. Anyway, remove me if OP posted his own answer.